# drop_na in RStudio

Tags: r, na, drop

I am unable to run the following on RStudio
penguins %>% group_by(island) %>% drop_na(.) %>% summarise(mean_bill_length_mm = mean(bill_length_mm))
The error coming up is
Error in drop_na(.) : could not find function "drop_na"
What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Add `library(tidyr)` before your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)
penguins %>% group_by(island) %>% drop_na(.) %>% summarise(mean_bill_length_mm = mean(bill_length_mm))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  island    mean_bill_length_mm
  <fct>                   <dbl>
1 Biscoe                   45.2
2 Dream                    44.2
3 Torgersen                39.0
```